# Is there any way to fix the side effect of "DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow" in VC6.0?

Tags: c++, windows, api, dwm

I have met an exactly problem which metioned in the MSDN Topic:[DWM Blur Behind Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969537.aspx).

After DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow was called, the client area became a beautiful glass, but unfortunatly, all of black text on the controls(BUTTONs,EDITs,STATICs etc) became transparent too, just like that [Topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969537.aspx).

Any way to fix this?

By the way, My develop env is VC++ 6.0, and I have to draw some glowing text with DrawThemeTextEx API, so I can't use DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea simplely. I MUST use DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow to enable the glass effect of client region.

Thanks a lot!

2012/6/19
Update:
By changing the TRANSPARENT KEY COLOR of a window to a non-black color with "SetLayeredWindowAttributes", then using "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea" can solve the caption text problem of CONTROLS(BUTTONs,EDITs etc) on the glass window.

But in this way, "DrawThemeTextEx" could not work properly. It looks like that DrawThemeTextEx could only use the RGB(0,0,0) as its TRANSPARENT KEY COLOR.

So, is there any API could change the TRANSPARENT KEY COLOR which used by "DrawThemeTextEx" within ?

My ultimate goal is to draw some glowing text on a glass(Aero) window without the  "DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow" side effects which metioned in the MSDN Topic:DWM Blur Behind Overview,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969537.aspx. 
And if there is another way to do it, I'm very glad to hear :)

And thanks a lot, again! :)

Comment: VC6 has nothing to do with it, the common controls use GDI and GDI does not support the alpha channel...

Comment: The reason I metioned VC6 is that I have to use DWM APIs in a dynamic way.  And the whole MSDEV is not as easily to use as VS2008 or later.

Comment: Using a color key is not the way to go IMHO since you need to choose a color that is not part of the theme/VS and not used in any graphics/icons you might have...

Comment: Yes, I have chosen a TRANSPARENT KEY COLOR:RGB(200, 201, 202) to make all the text displayed properly on the CONTROLS . But at the same time,"DrawThemeTextEx" could not work properly.   And  I'm really exhausted ..... My Goal is to make "DrawThemeTextEx" and "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea" works fine at the same time.  :(

Comment: and if the text system color is RGB(200, 201, 202) ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Painting the caption title](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx#appendixb) in MSDN:

Find the line `HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcPaint, hbm);` in the example.

Then, add this line after it:

```
// You should have set RGB(200,201,202) as the transparency key
FillRect(hdcPaint,&rcClient,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,201,202)));
```

Although the effect does not seem to be perfect, it solves the problem.

Reference: [C++ WinAPI Conflict between SetLayeredWindowAttributes and BitBlt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564457/c-winapi-conflict-between-setlayeredwindowattributes-and-bitblt/32908695#32908695)