# C++ WinAPI Conflict between SetLayeredWindowAttributes and BitBlt

Tags: c++, winapi, dwm

I have created a custom window using DWM. I painted the caption by using [`PaintCustomCaption()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx#appendixb) ,which is an example from MSDN. It worked properly until I added [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx).

Window before adding

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0,0,1),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
```

[image]

After adding

[image]

I tried changing RGB values but it was still black except RGB(0,0,0).

I wonder if `BitBlt()` works properly.

Edited:

The reason I added SetLayeredWindowAttributes is to solve this problem

[image]

Do you have other ways to paint the caption?

```
case WM_ACTIVATE: {
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd,&m); // m={-1,-1,-1,-1};
    break;
}
case WM_INITDIALOG: {
    SetWindowPos(hWnd,NULL,0,0,500,500,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd,GWL_STYLE,WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0,0,1),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
    RedrawWindow(hWnd,NULL,NULL,RDW_INVALIDATE|RDW_ERASE);
    return true;
}
case WM_PAINT: {
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&paintstruct);
    PaintCustomCaption(hWnd,hdc)
    EndPaint(hWnd,&paintstruct);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `BitBlt` "works properly". You have a bug in your code.

Comment: Are there any possible reasons that caused the bug?

Comment: Have you considered this Remark: `Note that once SetLayeredWindowAttributes has been called for a layered window, subsequent UpdateLayeredWindow calls will fail until the layering style bit is cleared and set again.`

Comment: @WilliamChan: How are we supposed to know without seeing your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use RGB(200,201,202) as the transparency key instead of RGB(0,0,1).

You may try other values but it is the best one so far I have tested.

Then, add this after `HBITMAP hbmOld=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcPaint,hbm);` in `PaintCustomCaption()`:

```
FillRect(hdcPaint,&rcClient,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(200,201,202)));
```

Comment: I have been looking for the solution for a quite long period of time and I finally found it!

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the window border, you don't need to paint the caption yourself unless you want to add something to your caption.

That is, handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and `WM_NCHITTEST` normally.